# Wants to echo new line character

Tags: ruby, linux, echo

I wants to echo \n like in this way using ruby language:

```
`echo "array = text.split(/\n/)" > demo`
```

and demo file should contain output in this way:

```
array = text.split(/\n/)
```

But instead to above i am getting in this way, \n produce new line in real which i dont want:

```
array = text.split(/
/)
```

Please let me know any options, I already tried backslash and ^ but none of this useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick with regexps, double-backslash your `\n`

```
`echo "array = text.split(/\\n/)" > demo`
```

Comment: Can you please change this answer? This is absolutely wrong..I tried this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use split("\n") instead of a regexp.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but this doesn't solve the escaping problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are 6 backslash needed here, Like this:

```
`echo "array = text.split(/\\\\\\n/)" > demo`
```

This produce excellent results.

Comment: Why don't you just write to a file rather than shelling out to `echo`? `File.open('demo', 'w')` is the way to do this.

Comment: Here i provide one line only, This line is part of big ruby script.

Comment: Fair enough, but you're still writing to a file and `echo` is a very odd way to go about doing that.

Comment: Can you suggest any other way instead to echo?

Comment: All that `echo` is doing is writing to a file, so why don't you just write to a file? Why the stubborn insistence on using `echo`?